# Как убрать все переносы строк с помощью RegEx?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как можно выбрать все переносы строк и заменить их пустой строкой?
Пытался сделать так:

```js
const reg = /\n+/g;

const str = `string1

string2


string3

string4

`

console.log(str.replace(reg, ''));
```

Полученный результат:

```
string1string2string3string4
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
```

Можно, конечно, заменить не на пустую строку, а на тот же символ переноса. Но можно ли получить желаемый результат без замены на перенос строки?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Получилось получить желаемый результат следующим выражением:

```js
const reg = /\s(?=(\n|\r|\r\n))/g;
```

Comment: `\s` находит *любой* пробельный символ. В вопросе речь идёт только о переносах строк.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Это работает без пробелов. Я корректно озвучил вопрос и дал корректный ответ.

Comment: Проблема именно в том, что "работает" и на пробелах. А согласно задаче, нужно удалить только знаки перевода строки.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew но это не так. Если в строке с текстом есть пробел, он никуда не денется. Если в пустой строке есть пробел, он так и останется.

Comment: Здесь `\s` удалит пробельный символ перед первым CR / LF.

Comment: Нет же. Работает аналогично, как ваш пример, только можно делать реплейс на пустую строку.

Comment: Сравните моё решение - `"Line 1 \r\n\r\n\r\nLine 2".replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n').replace('\r', '\\r').replace('\n', '\\n')` (=> `Line 1 \nLine 2`) - и ваше - `"Line 1 \r\n\r\n\r\nLine 2".replace(/\s(?=(\n|\r|\r\n))/g, '').replace('\r', '\\r').replace('\n', '\\n')` (=> `Line 1\nLine 2`). Ваше удалило пробел перед переносом строки.

Comment: Пробелы на месте - https://codepen.io/lmjavascriptprogrammer/pen/Exxqeea

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать

```
s = s.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n');
```

Выражение `/[\r\n]+/g` находит все совпадения одного и более знаков перевода каретки (CR, `\x0D`) или переноса строки (LF, `\x0A`) и шаблон замены `'\n'` заменяет их одним знаком LF.

Пример работы кода на JavaScript:

```js
const reg = /[\r\n]+/g;
const str = `string1

string2


string3

string4

`
console.log(str.replace(reg, '\n'));
```